# Why does the asp.net website administration tool give timeout message (mysql db)?

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, website-admin-tool

i have an asp.net-mvc website and I am trying to use the asp.net website administration tool but when i click in visual studio 2010 to launch it, it brings up a browser that says:

**An error was encountered. Please return to the previous page and try again.**

i can't click back but when i click on "How do i use this tool", i get this error:

**Tool Has Timed Out**

**As a security measure, the Web Site Administration Tool times out after a period of inactivity. Changes to machine.config or web.config may also result in the tool needing to be restarted. To continue configuring your web site, restart the tool.**

when i run my website, i am able to connect to the database fine and i am also able to insert new users through the default Account/LogOn interface.

Any suggestions on how to debug why i can't launch the admin tool ?

Comment: facing the same issue. Any luck ooo?

Comment: m too using mysql database. it was working, but suddenly stopped working.

Answer (score 2):

The project's path shouldn't contain #% or spaces

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try the following:

- Close your browser completely. Whether you are using IE or Firefox to test your website, you should make sure all browser windows are closed.
- Kill the asp.net development server. It is located in your taskbar
- Or, if you are hosting your site in IIS, force an iisreset.

Now try to run the Web Site Administration Tool again.

If it still does not work yet, could you please provide which browser you are using, and which OS and host?

Comment: i am running IE8 (but also tried in FF) and i am running on win XP

Answer (score 0):

The project's path shouldn't contain #% or spaces

My Project path was D:\Programming\C#\Tests\MVCApplication\
and that is what caused the problem.

Answer (score -2):

I was getting the exact same error message with VS2010 .NET 4.0 framework.  I created my solution in a subfolder titled "C#".  Renaming the subfolder to CSharp fixed my problem.

I hope this helps.